# IE 11 out of stack space issue es6-collections js with advanced bundling

Tags: magento2, jsbundling

We have enabled advanced JS bundling on magento 2.2.7. It works well in all browsers except IE11.

On IE11, it throws the following error on browser console.

Error Message : Out of stack space

file : es6-collections.js

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: It worked when I changed the following lines in the build.js from 

"MutationObserver": ["es6-collections"],

To

"MutationObserver": {
 "deps": [
   "es6-collections"
 ]
}

Comment: I'm not using bundling and it still breaks (IE 9 though). The es6-collection.js project is not maintained anymore and I guess we need another polyfill.